# How to create a file's path inside "~"

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I have an issue with Capistrano where `File.readlines` and `File.foreach` claim a file doesn't exist, but it does. When the error occurs, I can copy the error returned and `cat` or `nano` the file correctly.

```rb
if File.readlines("#{fetch(:application)}/.git/config").grep(/#{fetch(:old_repo_url)}/).size > 0
```

This outputs something like:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ~/Develop/homestead/code/projectname/.git/config
```

I can copy that and the location though and it *does* exist. Can it not read it because there's no file extension?

If I can't grep a git config file, is there maybe some other way to check if the git config currently contains the old repo URL variable?

If I could save the output of:

```
execute "cd #{fetch(:homestead_path)}/#{fetch(:application)}; git remote get-url origin"
```

to a variable, even to check, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a Capistrano issue.

In a path being processed by the shell `~` is expanded to the full path to your `$HOME`.

Ruby doesn't know what that would be, and assumes that `~` is a literal directory name, tries to open the file and it fails because `~` doesn't exist.

And, when you copy and test it from the shell, again, it expands `~` and you're convinced Ruby is wrong.

Fixing it is easy:

```
File.expand_path('~/.vimrc')   #=> "/Users/ttm/.vimrc"
```

Whatever is my current working directory will be used for relative files:

```
File.expand_path('.') #=> "/Users/ttm"
File.expand_path('..') #=> "/Users"
```

The [File](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/File.html) class has several methods like [`expand_path`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/File.html#method-c-expand_path) that are used to expand and convert paths. I'd suggest studying the documentation as they've very powerful and quite useful.